# Looking for online sources for historical currency data / exchange rates. Recommendations?

Tags: currency, online-data-source, recommendation, foreign-exchange

Is there any online service that provides (in any format whatsoever) historical foreign exchange rates, with bid/ask values? Intra-day would be preferred, but end-of-day is also of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three sites I can recommend:

- [ERS International Macroeconomic Data Set:](http://www.ers.usda.gov/Data/ExchangeRates/) This is annualised data put out by the US Department of Agriculture Economic Research Service and isn't too bad;
- [XE:](http://www.xe.com/) This is a commercial service which can supply a currency instream but also provides historical data and a fair amount of info available free from the site.
- [UN Data:](http://data.un.org/Search.aspx?q=exchange+rates) This is my favourite site for global data sourcing.  You sometimes have to hunt a bit but this search brought up quite a bit and you may find what you're looking for directly.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. Unfortunately, none of them seem to provide bid-ask spreads, let alone intra-date rates...

Comment: As a follow-up question, are you willing to pay for that service because I'm not sure that such data is available for free?  Otherwise - and I haven't explored this - I know Yahoo! has an API for stock activity, perhaps they also have something for exchange rates?

Comment: Indeed, it seems bad/ask data (certainly at low intervals, ticks even) is only available via paid services. I have however found one that seems suitable now. Thanks for your help; I'll accept this answer anyway.

Comment: @Noldorin why not link to your solution so the rest of us can enjoy the actual answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

[Dukascopy](http://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/)

- majors since 2007, tick by tick
- minors since 2010, tick by tick
- also covers XAUUSD and XAGUSD