# Sites to obtain historical chart of currency exchange rates?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency, yahoo-finance, online-data-source, websites

Besides [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=GBPMYR=X+Interactive#chart2%3asymbol=gbpmyr=x;range=5y;indicator=volume;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined), is there any site where I can obtain history chart of currency exchange, for cross comparison purpose?

(As I realize British Pound against my country currency is the lowest since 1999, I am planning to take this advantage to invest on the London Stock Exchange.)

Comment: Y! Finance isn't bad.  What do you want that it doesn't do?

Comment: Duplicate of http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/looking-for-online-sources-for-historical-currency-data-exchange-rates-recomme

Comment: @Dheer Not a duplicate.  This question is specifically asking for a site to provide a **chart** of price history.  The other question is asking about data sources of any kind (probably in a more consumable format, as opposed to a graphic.)  *Related*, yes, but not the same question.

Comment: @mbhunter For cross comparison purpose, in order to give me certain degree of confidence, on the data accuracy.

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are usually considered offtopic, since the pointers tend to become obsolete relatively quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OANDA has a free online tool (a Java applet) that will do what you're asking.  Description:

> **Currency Graph FXGraph:**
>   Plot the
>   change between two currencies over any
>   time period
>
> Make a customized graph of historical
>   exchange rates for two of over 190
>   currencies, for any time period since
>   1990.
>   [...]

Visit [Currency Graph | OANDA](http://www.oanda.com/currency/graph).